# How do I fix a Flutter for Android issue?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm doing an app in Android Studio, and decided to make a Flutter project since it would help me a lot, but I seem to be running into a problem that I've seen no one have. On my MainActivity in the android/app/src/main folder, I have it extend FlutterActivity but it's showing an error, not being able to find io.flutter.embedding. When I go to Project Structure, it tells me that I have an invalid item 'Flutter for Android' in the dependencies list of my 'myappname.android' module. I have downloaded the Flutter SDK and I have the project pointing there, but other than that I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any ideas? [Flutter doctor diagnosis, if asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBuEZ.png)

Edit: Provided an image of the errors:

[Dependency error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk3V7.png)

[Library error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBCOq.png)

[MainActivity error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUk2x.png)

Comment: I have `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity` above my `class` in the `MainActivity.kt` file.

Comment: Yes I have it too, and it's why I described that it was also giving me an error on that import. Which I assume is because I'm missing 'Flutter for Android' in the dependencies list, but I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was entirely my bad, I had no idea I had to open both Flutter Project and the Android Module of said project on Android Studio. Everything is working great now, thanks and sorry!

Comment: How did you open both?

Comment: I did so by opening the Android Module on a new window in Android Studio, essentially having both Flutter Project and the Android Module opened in two separate instances of Android Studio

Comment: I'm using Intellij With the Android Studio and Flutter plugins. How would I go about this now?